# Why aren't pointers to member functions just memory address like data pointers

Tags: c++, c

I realized from [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr.html) FAQ entry that one cannot convert a pointer to member function to/from `void*`. The reason being pointers to members are not memory addresses exactly like pointers to data! Why so? Please help me get clarified. And this isn't necessarily with member functions but any normal C functions as well, isn't?

Comment: IMHO - Pointers to functions in C++ is a bad idea since there are better alternatives. (virtual functions and inheritance)

Comment: Check the next FAQ entry [Can I convert a pointer-to-function to a void*?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/cant-cvt-fnptr-to-voidptr.html)

Comment: Also IMHO using `void *` is also a bad idea in both C and C++

Comment: @EdHeal, In C it can be the only way to achieve certain kind of polymorphism.

Comment: @Jefffrey - I agree but it is best avoided

Comment: Also can you please clarify what would be useful in converting such a function pointer to `void*`?

Comment: @Jefffrey. Was curious. My understanding was that any pointers resolve into some memory address. And hence the surprise that function pointers to/from void* do not hold good!

Comment: @nos No, a pointer to a member function is independent of a particular object. That's why you have to provide an object at the call site: `(someObject.*p)();`.

Comment: @Ed Heal : pointers to functions is not required for polymorphism, but extremely handy for other things such as object factories.

Comment: Anyway in C++ virtual functions and inheritance are *not* a universally better alternative to function pointers. Templates can use function pointers, they're just another functor. Granted, pointer-to-member-function and pointer-to-function are different categories, and templates generally deal in the latter rather than the former.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> pointers to members are not memory addresses exactly like pointers to data! Why so?

Pointers to member functions need to indicate whether the function is virtual, and allow virtual dispatch (perhaps by specifying the index into the vtable, rather than the address of a specific function) if so. This makes them more complicated than just an address.

> And this isn't necessarily with member functions but any normal C functions as well, isn't?

Pointers to "normal" (non-member) functions may be converted to object pointers, but not portably. Quoting the standard:

> C++11 5.2.10/8 Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, [...]

On many platforms, a (non-member) function pointer is simply a memory address, and the conversion is well-defined. Some platforms have more exotic memory architectures - for example, separate memory spaces for instructions and data - and the conversion may not be allowed on those platforms.

Comment: Separate spaces for functions and data makes sense. But still, all entities should resolve into one address, isn't? Why prohibit conversions into address where functions are located?

Comment: @Prabhu: because you assume that a pointer to member-function points into the function space, but it is not necessarily so. To implement support for `virtual` pointers and `virtual` inheritance they might carry *data*.

Comment: @Prabhu: "all entities should resolve into one address" - not if there are separate address spaces for instructions and data. An address in instruction space is not usable as an address in data space, so should not be convertible to one.

Comment: Your question appears to be about pointers to *member functions* rather than just *members* - that is not clear from the title.

Comment: @Prabhu, most microcontrollers follow the Harvard model of having separate program and data address spaces. The program address space is usually linear but the data address space is often implemented using bank switching. Therefore a pointer into the data space has a completely different representation than a pointer into the address space with the former being complex objects and not simply numbers.

Answer (score 4):

#### In the C++ standard

As the [next FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/cant-cvt-fnptr-to-voidptr.html) says:

> The language does not require functions and data to be in the same address space, so, by way of example and not limitation, on architectures that have them in different address spaces, the two different pointer types will not be comparable.

In §5.2.10/8 (of N3936 specifically) the standard specifies that this is indeed *implementation defined*:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv- qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

Here the behavior is well specified.

#### In the C standard

The C standard doesn't appear to contemplate the conversion from a function pointer to an object pointer. In fact it barely draws a line between them.

It just states, at §6.3.2.3/8, that:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

At this point the behavior almost seems to be *unspecified*.

And then later in §6.5.9/6:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Here we can see the only trace of an actual difference in:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are [..] pointers to the same object (..) **or** function [..].

#### The why

As for the "why", it appears to be dependent on the fact that some architectures simply have functions and objects in two address space.

Comment: In some x86-16 memory models, data and function pointers could even be different *sizes*.